# How to add labels on top of polygons in leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, polygons, r-leaflet

I am working with the leaflet `R` package. I have a **zoning** system made of polygons and I'd like to lay their IDs on top of them. Below is an illustration (with another software) of my objective.

[image]

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since there is no reproducible data, I decided to use one of my previous posts related to leaflet. There are two things you want to take away from this post: 1) you need to create a data frame containing center points of target regions, 2) you need to use `addLabelOnlyMarkers()`. You can achieve the first thing using `gCentroid()`. I added row names of the polygon data set (UK) as character to `centers`. This is used for labeling. You need to think what labels you use in your own case. Once this data set is ready, you want to use it in `addLabelOnlyMarkers()`.

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(leaflet)

# Get UK polygon data
UK <- getData("GADM", country = "GB", level = 2)

# Find a center point for each region
centers <- data.frame(gCentroid(UK, byid = TRUE))
centers$region <- row.names(UK)

### Create dummy data
set.seed(111)
mydf <- data.frame(place = unique(UK$NAME_2),
                   value = sample.int(n = 1000, size = n_distinct(UK$NAME_2), replace = TRUE))

### Create five colors for fill
mypal <- colorQuantile(palette = "RdYlBu", domain = mydf$value, n = 5, reverse = TRUE)

leaflet() %>% 
addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
setView(lat = 55, lng = -3, zoom = 6) %>%
addPolygons(data = UK,
            stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 0.3,
            fillColor = ~mypal(mydf$value),
            popup = paste("Region: ", UK$NAME_2, "<br>",
                          "Value: ", mydf$value, "<br>")) %>%
addLabelOnlyMarkers(data = centers,
                    lng = ~x, lat = ~y, label = ~region,
                    labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE, direction = 'top', textOnly = TRUE)) %>%
addLegend(position = "bottomright", pal = mypal, values = mydf$value,
          title = "UK value",
          opacity = 0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a beautiful example, thank you.  I would also like to link to this answer which I found very helpful for non convex polygons: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/265475/78424

Comment: @geneorama Thanks for your words. Much appreciated! Thanks for leaving a useful link here as well.

Comment: @jazzurro, great answer. How to change font size when zooming in/out.  When the labels are names it becomes weird when zooming out. Is there a way to change the font size or make the text label disappear?