# Is there any way that to display zip codes on the face of an interactive map created with R leaflet package?

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I mapped overdose deaths of Philadelphia by zip code: https://6abc.com/5978005/
I wanted to display zip codes on the face of the map but couldn't figure out how to. This is what I wanted my map to look like:
[Philadelphia Overdose Deaths Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bJ4I.jpg)

Is there any function I can use to display zip codes on the face of the map like this?

Comment: Don't know of a function but there is a whole package here `tidycensus` here: https://walkerke.github.io/tidycensus/articles/basic-usage.html You can use the variable `zcta` for zipcode. Take a look.

Comment: One approach is to calculate the centroid for each zip code (with `gCentroid` from `rgeos` package), and then use `addLabelOnlyMarkers` using the centroid information. An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48147823/3460670).